# Android call Activity in background

Tags: java, android, android-activity, background, phone-call

I'm currently trying to place a call in the background.
Therefore I call this in my Main-Activity:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I also wrote an Outgoing Call Receiver which changes the activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, DisplayCalcActivity.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

The problem is now, that the call-screen is in the foreground. If I switch manually from the call screen to my app, the activity has changed as I wanted, but how is it possible to start the activity in the foreground, so that the call-screen won't be shown at all?

Comment: You might make the call within a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and have the foreground on the service. then you are able to have it in foreground without having it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK does not allow to make a call in "foreground" maybe you can do accessing to private members but this is not recommended. The only way to call is by dialer app.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution!

I used another Receiver to listen to "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE".
The outgoing call, activates the receiver which starts the other activity.